# Display Names for List of Sub Entities of Sub Entities of Parent

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have:

```cs
public class Parent
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Children?>? childs {get; set;}
}

public class Children
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public ICollection<GrandChildren> kids{get; set;}
}

public class GrandChildren
{
    public int id{get; set;}
    public string name{get; set;}
}
```

I want to display the Names (id,name) of my Grandchildren in the View, but .NET is unable to see them.

Details.cshtml: (works)

```html
@model Parent
<table class="table">  
    <tbody>
            @foreach (Children ch in Model.Children)
        {
            var grandchild = ch.OldestKid();
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => grandchild.name)
                </td>
                </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This works.
Now I would like to show the Header, but it is apparently not possible to use my GrandChildren class:

```html
<thead>             
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.childs.kids.name) //not possible
            </th>
```

...**How do I use my GrandChildren Parameters here?**
Would also like to know the solution for "<input asp-for="model.Children.GrandChildren"....".

Answer (score 1):

You can use two `@foreach()` to get the value of GrandChildren' Name

```
@model Parent
<table class="table">  
    <thead>
                 <tr>
                     @foreach (var child in @Model.childs)
                     {
                         @foreach (var GrandChild in child.kids)
                         {
                             <th>
                                 @GrandChild.name                                
                                 
                             </th>
                         }
                     }
                 </tr>
             </thead>
</table>
```

**Demo**

[image]

If you want to use Input to change the value of GrandChildren' Name, you need to use `List<T>` instead of `ICollection<T>` in your model, Then add index in `asp-for` tag:

```
@model Parent
@{
    int i = 0; 
}

<form method="post">
    @foreach (var child in @Model.childs)
    {

       
        int j = 0;
        @foreach(var gradnchild in @child.kids)
        { 
            <th>
               @gradnchild.name 
               <br/>
               <input asp-for=@Model.childs[@i].kids[@j].name/>
                                 
            </th>
            j++; 
        } 
        i++;
    }
    
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Your answer would produce n*m Grandchildren Tableheaders, what I want is one Table Header.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have found a single Website with a simple Solution for that.

1.)Directly with the Collections:

```
 @Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>Model.childs.First().kids.First().name)
```

Or even easier:

2.) With a different Method:

```
@Html.DisplayNameForInnerType((GrandChildren d) => d.name)
```

Somehow this can retrieve the Subentities directly.

Just wrap it in the HTML Elements and done:

```
<table> 
 <thread>
 <tr>
  <th>
    @Html.DisplayNameForInnerType((GrandChildren d) => d.name)
  </th>
 <tr>
 </thead>
```